# Custom API function

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and Angular to build an app. I have created Serializers and ModelViewSet classes for my models that I want to be accessed in the front-end by Angular.

It all works fine at the moment but I would like to have functionality beyond basic operations.

Right now, I can only perform CRUD queries from my front-end service. But, I would like to create a functions that would 'get most recent' or something that is more specific.

Preferably, I would like to have the back-end model communicate with its corresponding Angular resource.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is documented heavily in the docs for viewsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define custom endpoints in your Django viewset.

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing the accounts
    associated with the user.
    """
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAccountAdminOrReadOnly]

    @list_route(methods=['get'])
    def get_most_recent(self):
        <get the most recent account code here>
        return Request(data, status=200)
```

Then in your angular code you just make a request to the proper endpoint... something like `http://yoururl.com/accounts/get_most_recent`. You can do this with any REST verbs (GET, POST...) by defining which verbs you want to accept in the methods array.

Docs are here:http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between list_route and detail_route?

Comment: list_route is a general request to an endpoint. detail_route sends a primary key and is used to access a specific resource. A list_route would be like .com/user and a detail_route would be like .com/user/1234 (1234 being a specific user id number). Its all in the docs.
Also if this helped, please accept my answer.